# Усечение файла

Tags: unix, c

Задание разработать функцию, которая усекает существующий файл до указанных размеров
Думал, что пройдёт такой вариант с добавлением EOF'a в нужном месте.

```
int n;
printf("input colvo simvolov\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
FILE *f;
f= fopen(file , "rb+");
n--;
for(;n>0;n--) getc(f);
fputc(4,f);
```

В итоге просто печатается на это место символ. Можно этот способ доработать? Или есть более изящное решение?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

На никсах самый простой способ изменить размер файла - использование системных вызовов truncate() и ftruncate().

Смотри man 2 truncate

Если нужно использовать только библиотечные стандартные функции, напиши, придумаем код.

Comment: А я других и не знаю (чтобы действительно тот же файл (номер инода) остался).

Comment: Ну да, чтобы сохранить inod, пожалуй, другого варианта нет.

Comment: Хотя вот: 

копируем нужное количество байтов во временный файл

открываем исходный файл с O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC

записываем в него содержимое временного файла.

Тот же алгоритм для стандартных функций.

Comment: в том и дело что нужно как бы разработать системную функцию. 
то есть остаётся только вариант скопировать сколько нужно в буфер а оттуда потом в переоткрытый начальный файл?

Comment: Не понятно: так можно использовать системные вызовы?

Comment: Разработайте системную функцию, которая усекает существующий файл до произвольных размеров, указанных в качестве аргумента, и опишите ее работу. 
Вот чёткое задание. Я так понимаю нет.

Comment: Ну, если с truncate никак, то как я описал. В буфер в памяти имеет смысл копировать, только если файл небольшой. Если же объем велик, то нужно скопировать во временный файл, потом из него, а его удалить.

Еще вариант (если не важно сохранение inod): после копирования во временный файл уничтожаем начальный, а временному даем имя начального файла.

EOF == 0. Ну добавится ноль где-то в файле. Это может только повлиять на чтение в текстовом режиме, а на длину это никак не может повлиять.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. 
А почему не работает добавление EOF в нужное место??

Answer (score 2):

По поводу EOF в нужное место.

Вы пишете 4 (Ctrl-D) в файл. В Unix  это просто символ, ничем не отличающийся от других. Вы путаете его с ^D, который, когда вводится **с клавиатуры** закрывает входной поток. На самом деле так на него реагирует **драйвер клавиатуры**, который и закрывает поток. Кстати, ^D можно переопределить, посмотрите команду stty.

Из Вашего комментария *"Разработайте системную функцию"*, скорее всего следует, что требуется разработать **не системный вызов**, а команду (типа ls).

Поэтому смело используйте truncate().